# Using an integer variable into an XPath expression Java to extract info from repeating nodes with namespaces

Tags: java, xpath

Solved! Thank you guys!

Your suggestions led me to the answer. So all of you deserve thanks for the suggestion.

The solution to putting a int variable is the following:

```
//Put my xpath into a string variable where it can evaluate my integer "counter"

String myString = "/*[local-name()='root' and namespace-uri()='DK']/*[local-name()='book' and namespace-uri()='DK']" + counter + "]/*[local-name()='item1' and namespace-uri()='DK']/*[local-name()='item2' and namespace-uri()='DK']/*[local-name()='date' and namespace-uri()='DK'][" + counter + "]"


//Then simply put that string variable into the xpath expression.
System.out.print(myString);
```

Original Question below:

Firstly, I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance for any help.

I have an XML file that I need to parse.

Lets say for example...

```
<root xmlns="DK">
  <book>
    <item1>
      <item2>
        <date>xxx
        </date>
        <date>x1x1x1
        </date>
      </item2>
    </item1>
  </book>
  <book>
    <item1>
      <item2>
        <date>yyy
        </date>
        <date>y1y1y1
        </date>
      </item2>
    </item1>
  </book>    
</root>
```

So basically, I'm looking for the node < date> with xxx and then move on to the same node < date> in the next book which contains yyy.

The input xml file will have an unknown amount of repeating books with different information for each book.

I've chosen to try something like this.

```
// I've imported from dom4j SAXreader. I probably could use something different.
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;



// Variables
Document document = null;       

// Take input from file    
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
document = reader.read("E:/templates/test.xml");

int counter = 0;
int numofbooks = 0;

Element root = document.getRootElement();

for ( Iterator i = root.elementIterator("book"); i.hasNext();) {
    Element element = (Element) i.next();

counter = counter + 1;
numofbooks = counter;
}

System.out.println("There are " + numofbooks + " books required for processing");
while(counter != numofbooks); {
counter = counter + 1;

System.out.print("The values are: ");

// ----- This here is my problem code ----- //
System.out.print(/*[local-name()='root' and namespace-uri()='DK']/*[local-name()='book' and namespace-uri()='DK'][counter]/*[local-name()='item1' and namespace-uri()='DK']/*[local-name()='item2' and namespace-uri()='DK']/*[local-name()='date' and namespace-uri()='DK'][counter]).getStringValue());


System.out.print(" respectively");
}
```

My problem lies here. Because there are a few repeated nodes with the exact same name that are nested, I'm grabbing them out by number using an integer counter variable.

My XPath expression doesn't understand that I'm putting in a variable "counter" that is an integer.

Is there any syntax I can use to make this work?
Or is it just not possible?

Thanks in advance.

DK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to a variable `$counter` in your XPath expression, and you can set the value of the variable from the Java API by defining an XPathVariableResolver and associating it with your XPathFactory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any calls to the [XPath API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) in your code, just a very confusing XPath expression in a comment.

The following code gets you a `NodeList` of the **first** `<date>` in **each** `<item2>`:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList dates = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/DK:root/DK:book/DK:item1/DK:item2/DK:date[1]", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < dates.getLength(); i++) {
    Node item = dates.item(i);
    String content = item.getTextContent().trim();
    System.err.println(content);
}
```

Given the XML snippet in your question, the above code will output:

```
xxx
yyy
```

Note that XPath starts counting from 1, so `date[1]` is the first element, not the second as it would be in Java.

If you don't need namespace awareness, you can use just  `"/root/book/item1/item2/date[1]"` (and probably remove a call to `DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);` or equivalent)

If `item2` is unique in the whole document, you can even reduce the XPath expression to `"//item2/date[1]`" (for NS awareness, prefix both path segments with `DK:` as above).

Comment: In order to achieve namespace-awareness correctly, he'd also have to [set the namespace context](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext(javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext)) to bind the prefix to the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

**Even if there is nestedness that isn't known in advance**, one can use an XPath expression like:

```
(//*[local-name()='root' and namespace-uri()='DK'])[$k]
```

where `$k` can be substituted with a positive integer.

**Do note**:

1. The brackets in the above expression are necessary.
2. Indexing in XPath is 1 - based, not 0 -based as in C# or C++.

Comment: I've tried [$k] and I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. I'm not sure why because the syntax looks right... there must be something I'm doing wrong,

Comment: Have you implemented `XPathVariableResolver` in a way that links the variable name to your counter, as suggested by Michael Kay?

Comment: Sorry, I was doing a getStringValue(); on it. It returns 'null' if I put in a [$k] but works if I put in an actual number. I haven't tried the XPathVariableResolver... I'm looking into it now.

Comment: @DKImportant: Yes, you should convert the value to string. In C# I'd write: `string.format("(//*[local-name()='root' and namespace-uri()='DK'])[$k]", i);`